# OracleParameterCollection giving me weird errors

Tags: c#, oracle

```
Error   CS1729  'OracleParameterCollection' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

My Code

```
OracleParameterCollection oracleParameter = new OracleParameterCollection(); <====== How do I create one?
oracleParameter.Add("User_Name", OracleDbType.Char).Value = UserName;
oracleParameter.Add("Entered_Password", OracleDbType.Char).Value = Password;
oracleParameter.Add("T1_Cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
DataTable employeeDataTable = StoredProcedureCall.GenerateStoredProcedureCall(_connectionString, "GET_USER_INFO_BY_CREDENTIALS", oracleParameter, out temp);
```

Method in class

```
    public DataTable GenerateStoredProcedureCall(String _connectionString, String StoredProcedure_Name, OracleParameterCollection ParameterNames, out String ResultFromDatabaseOperation)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandText = StoredProcedure_Name;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.BindByName = true;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParameterNames);                        
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);
                ResultFromDatabaseOperation = "";
                if (cmd.Parameters["RowCount"].Value != null)
                {
                    ResultFromDatabaseOperation = cmd.Parameters["RowCount"].Value.ToString();
                }
                if (cmd.Parameters["RowCount"].Value == null)
                {
                    ResultFromDatabaseOperation = "0";
                }                    
                return dt;
            }
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            ResultFromDatabaseOperation = "";
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Um, what language / development environment is this?

Comment: It is in C#. I had tagged it with my question

Comment: That is not the intended usage of the class, you usually add the parameters to the Command that will be executed.

Comment: How would I pass a collection of Oracle parameters to my Class?

Comment: Consider editing your question and adding a [mcve] so you could get better help. As is, I would suggest having a method to add a parameter and calling it as many times as needed

Comment: @bradbury9 updated the question with the minimal reproducible example

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit its already in the question. DataTable employeeDataTable = StoredProcedureCall.GenerateStoredProcedureCall...

Comment: When you check documentation then you see there is no constructor for `OracleParameterCollection`. I would suggest a simple `List<OracleParameter>` which you pass to your procedure.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I like that idea! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `StoredProcedureCall.GenerateStoredProcedureCall()` is your own defined function, then You should not pass `OracleParameterCollection` list to it. You can create simple dictionary and pass to this function. 
And then inside the function you can add parameter directly to command. i.e:

```
foreach(var i in params)
{
    oraCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(i.key, i.val));
}
```

There is no need to create new instance of `OracleParameterCollection`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is passing the parameters into my GenerateStoredProcedureCall. There are more than 45 SP that we plan on using. Some are 1 parameter (which is ParameterDirection.Output) and others are upto 17 parameters. Some pass in a value (like "John") and others are a Date. So I wanted to define the Parameter with all configured options then pass it to my defined function to do the appropriate task